# Taxonomy Page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy in WordPress with a custom template, below is dummy link

http://localhost/projects/countries/canada/ (For this I have used taxonomy-country.php)

This is working fine, but when someone visits the link

http://localhost/projects/countries (For this I have created category.php or archive.php, but nor is working)

Page Not found error comes, is there any way to may this work, I need a custom template for this.??

Below is my code for Custom Taxonomy

```
 $country_labels = array(
            'name' => __('Country', 'projects'),
            'singular_name' => __('Country', 'projects'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Country', 'projects'),
            'all_items' => __('All Country', 'projects'),
            'parent_item' => __('Parent Country', 'projects'),
            'parent_item_colon' =>__('Parent Country:', 'projects'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Country', 'projects'),
            'update_item' => __('Update Country', 'projects'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Country', 'projects'),
            'new_item_name' => __('Country Name', 'projects'),
            'menu_name' => __('Country', 'projects')
        );

        $country_args = array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'labels'            => $country_labels,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => __('countries', 'projects') ),
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'country', 'projects', $country_args );
```

Comment: The urls you have posted are localhost. They are no use here.

Comment: @MurshidAhmed: That are sample URL

Comment: Try adding `'has_archive'  =>  true` to `$country_args` and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, we can create a page with category name and create a template for same.

Like, we can create a page countries, which worked for me..